# Text processing in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I need to process first line if second line matches to "Minion did not return". My text is as follows:

```
t-dat-collectorsrv-1a.2014_12_01_11_23:
    True
t-dat-postprocessorsrv-1a.2014_04_29_10_02:
    True
t-dat-collectorsrv-1a.2014_12_03_10_15:
    Minion did not return
t-dat-collectorsrv-1a.2014_12_03_10_27:
    Minion did not return
t-dat-collectorsrv-1a.2014_12_03_10_38:
    Minion did not return
```

Whenever I get 'Minion did not return' I want to get the first line "t-dat-*" and want to do some processing. How can I separate first line based on output printed on second line?

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to store the previous line and act upon it if the current line matches a pattern:

```
$ awk '/Minion did not return/{print prev;prev=$0}{prev=$0}' inputFileName

t-dat-collectorsrv-1a.2014_12_03_10_15:
t-dat-collectorsrv-1a.2014_12_03_10_27:
t-dat-collectorsrv-1a.2014_12_03_10_38:
```

In the above transcript, it's simply printing out the previous line but you can do more complicated stuff with it as well:

```
$ awk '
    /Minion did not return/ {
        print gensub(/^[^.]*\.(....).(..).(..).(..).(..).*$/,
            "\\1-\\2-\\3 \\4:\\5", "g", prev);
        prev=$0
    }
    {
        prev=$0
    }' qq.in

2014-12-03 10:15
2014-12-03 10:27
2014-12-03 10:38
```

Comment: Thanks paxdiablo! That worked like a charm. I want to learn 'sed' and 'awk' but  find most of the links more confusing. Can you give me some insights about which book or link I should refer for this?

Comment: @user2964886, for learning `sed` and `awk`, there's a book I'm quite fond of, if only I could remember the name.  ... That's it, it's called "sed & awk" :-)  http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do. If you don't want to shell out your hard-earned for the dead-tree edition, have a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html.